# Backpropagation for sigmoid activation and softmax output

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to build a L layer neural network for multi-class classification with softmax activation in the output layer and sigmoid activation in other layers.

The function used for training looks like this:

```
def L_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate=0.01, num_iterations=5000, print_cost=True): 
"""
Implements a L-layer neural network: [LINEAR->SIGMOID]*(L-1)->LINEAR->SOFTMAX.

Arguments:
X -- data, numpy array of shape (number of features, number of examples)
Y -- true "label" vector of shape (number of classes, number of examples)
layers_dims -- list containing the input size and each layer size, of length (number of layers + 1).
learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
print_cost -- if True, it prints the cost every 100 steps

Returns:
parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. They can then be used to predict.
"""

np.random.seed(1)
costs = []                         # keep track of cost

# Parameters initialization.

parameters = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims)
L = len(parameters) // 2   # number of layers in the neural network
forward_calculated = {}
m = Y.shape[1]


# Loop (gradient descent)
for i in range(0, num_iterations):

    # Forward propagation: [LINEAR -> SIGMOID]*(L-1) -> LINEAR -> SOFTMAX.
    A = X
    forward_calculated["A0"] = X
    for l in range(1, L+1):   
        A_prev = A
        #print(A_prev)

        W = parameters['W' + str(l)]
        b = parameters['b' + str(l)]
        #print("W.shape: "+str(W.shape))
        #print("A_prev.shape: "+str(A_prev.shape))
        #print("b.shape: "+str(b.shape))
        Z = np.dot(W, A_prev) + b
        #Z = np.matmul(W, A_prev) + b

        assert(Z.shape == (W.shape[0], A.shape[1]))
        forward_calculated["Z" + str(l)] = Z   # store for future use

        if l != L:  # except the last layer
            A = sigmoid(Z)
        else:
            A = softmax(Z)

        #print("A is a tuple: ", end='')
        #print(isinstance(A, tuple))

        forward_calculated["A" + str(l)] = A   # store for future use

    assert(forward_calculated["A" + str(L)].shape == (NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, X.shape[1]))


    # Compute cost.
    Y_hat = forward_calculated["A" + str(L)]
    cost = compute_multiclass_loss(Y, Y_hat)

    #cost = compute_cost(AL, Y)

    # now back propagation

    grads = {}
    grads['dZ' + str(L)] = forward_calculated["A" + str(L)] - Y
    grads['dW' + str(L)] = (1./m) * np.dot(grads['dZ' + str(L)], forward_calculated["A" + str(L-1)].T)
    grads['db' + str(L)] = (1./m) * np.sum(grads['dZ' + str(L)], axis=1, keepdims=True)

    for l in range(L-1, 0, -1):
        grads['dA' + str(l)] = np.dot(parameters["W" + str(l+1)].T, grads['dZ' + str(l+1)])
        #dA1 = np.matmul(W2.T, dZ2)
        grads['dZ' + str(l)] = grads['dA' + str(l)] * sigmoid(forward_calculated["Z" + str(l)]) * (1 - sigmoid(forward_calculated["Z" + str(l)]))
        #dZ1 = dA1 * sigmoid(Z1) * (1 - sigmoid(Z1))
        grads['dW' + str(l)] = (1./m) * np.dot(grads['dZ' + str(l)], forward_calculated["A" + str(l-1)].T)
        #dW1 = (1./m) * np.matmul(dZ1, X.T)
        grads['db' + str(l)] = (1./m) * np.sum(grads['dZ' + str(l)], axis=1, keepdims=True)
        #db1 = (1./m) * np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True)


    # Update parameters.

    for l in range(1,L+1):
        #print("grads[dW]: " + str(grads["dW" + str(l)]));
        parameters["W" + str(l)] = parameters["W" + str(l)] - learning_rate * grads["dW" + str(l)]
        #print("grads[db]: " + str(grads["db" + str(l)]));
        parameters["b" + str(l)] = parameters["b" + str(l)] - learning_rate * grads["db" + str(l)]

    # Print the cost every 100 training example
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
        print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" % (i, cost))

        costs.append(cost)

print(costs)
# plot the cost
plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
plt.show()

return parameters
```

When I have only one hidden layer, the code works fine and the model gradually converges. However, when I have more than one hidden layer, the model doesn't seem to converge. It predicts all the examples to be of the same class. Is there any error in my formula of back propagation? The cost function I am using is the log loss.

```
def compute_multiclass_loss(Y, Y_hat):   # Y -> actual, Y_hat -> predicted

L_sum = np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(Y_hat)))
m = Y.shape[1]
L = -(1/m) * L_sum

L = np.squeeze(L)      # To make sure your cost's shape is what we expect (e.g. this turns [[17]] into 17).
assert(L.shape == ())
return L
```

In short, my question is, are these formula true (for log loss and softmax activation at the output and sigmoid activation at other layers)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be fine,
however these is a conceptual problem called Gradient Vanishing.

When you use deep network you can see as u go near to input layers, in the calculation of gradient, number of derivative of sigmoid increases.

The maximum value of derivative of sigmoid is 0.25, and that is not always the case, value of derivative of sigmoid can be near to like 0.001 or something, in that case when these small terms increases, Gradient is decreased drastically.

So, ReLU is one thing that can solve this problem to some extent, its derivative is either 0 or 1, so if gradient vanish it would be due to only weights and not Activation.

So, **USE ReLU in hidden Layer instead of Sigmoid**

This article in the book by Michael Nielsen explains this in depth with calculus

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap5.html#the_vanishing_gradient_problem